# How do you reuse code in python package while keeping func-names short

Tags: python

I have in **debug.py**:

```
class Debug(object):
     import pprint
     pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
```

In module **foo.py**:

```
class Foo(Debug):
      Debug.pp.pprint(CONFIG)
```

Is there a way to reuse helper functions in a short and easy manner.
*Debug.pp.pprint(CONFIG)* is considerably longer than *debug(CONFIG)*

Comment: Why do you `import` *inside* a class? Why is `pp` in a class at all? And why don't you access it via `self`?

Comment: Mostly because I'm not comfortable with the language. I know the syntax (Beazley - PER) but I'm not able to write tersely. I normally stick all my imports at the top of the module if it's a standalone module but I'm working on a package and it's proving more confusing (working out the namespaces). self is for an 'instance'.. i could do self.debug() IF my class provided a debug method - but this is for a package so i have other module files with 1 class/file; in this case I wanted to inherit the debug method from another class 'Debug'

Comment: are there any python books that deal with when to use a class, method, function, module and pkg.. or could you suggest well written python packages that i could take a look at

Comment: But `Debug` doesn't define a `debug` method (or any method, for that matter - it has a *class attribute* that is an instance of `PrettyPrinter`). It is not clear why you want to `pprint(CONFIG)` at `Foo` definition time. In general, there are many ways of structuring this, but without more information it's hard to say what would be best for your project. Resource recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm using **__init__**to initialize a dictionary CONFIG, read from a YAML file. I need to pprint(CONFIG) within the class to check if i got it right - i was passing CONFIG['src_address'] to a method in that class and it was b0rking. regarding 'pp' yeah i was toying with the idea of sticking it in a method but i wasn't sure how to handle it (you can't use 'self' and @staticmethod would be silly or well.. maybe i'd want some kind of additional transaction logging so i didn't want to get rid of the class.. I know a class is used to specialize stuff but what else and how, under what conditions?

Comment: That is much too broad a question to be addressed here.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you need the Debug class here (and extend it). A better option is to create shortcurts on the module level:

```
# in debug.py:

def pp(x):
    pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).print(x)
```

and then

```
from debug import pp

pp(whatever)
```

Comment: Even simpler, just put `pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).print` in `debug.py`.